# Cassandra data modeling to query on many columns

Tags: cassandra, database, nosql

I have kind of object (record) that has dynamic attributes (up to hundred of attributes). With the fact that I don't know what attributes that object would have because it's determined by end users, i think i should use map type to store attributes and their values with Cassandra.

I would have like 2 query patterns for now:

1. Look for some `last` records with given `attribute<X>=<value>`
2. Look for all records with given `attribute<x>=<value>` grouped by `attribute<y>` with recorded time is between a `time range`

`<x>` and `<y>` are non-determined at design time. It varies as end user defines it.

Because collection types can't be used as part of primary key so I wonder if there is any good way to model this or i will need to rely on secondary indexes. I hesitate to use secondary indexes because it needs to query on all Cassandra nodes.

So, my questions is, how can model Cassandra key spaces for my requirements?

For further discussions:

1. I'm thinking on create separated key spaces for each attribute name (when a user defines one, i would have to create one key spaces), am i abusing key spaces? I think I am.
2. Do i need to rely on secondary indexes?

P/s: I'm new to Cassandra so pardon me if i misused any terms.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your need, you can create a table `records` that store common properties such as `time` as static columns, and two fields `name` and `value` to store key value pair attributes.

`CREATE TABLE record (
    record_id uuid,
    time date static,
    name string,
    value string,
    PRIMARY KEY (record_id)
);`

Provide as is, this table can only be query by `record_id`. To add more query complexity, you can use `MATERIALIZED VIEW` :

`CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW record_by_attribute 
AS 
SELECT *
FROM record
WHERE record_id IS NOT NULL
    AND name IS NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY ((name, record_id);`

With this structure, you can run query for your first query pattern :

`SELECT *
FROM record_by_attribute
WHERE name = 'an attribute'
LIMIT 10;`

For your second need, i think you have to create a second table to store aggregation results for all attribute combinations (cassandra does not support GROUP BY clause) and query it like i said above.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: This really a good idea i think, however i need all the attributes along the records whenever i get it from Cassandra, with this model, i think i will have to denormalize data so much? What do you think @Guilaume?

Comment: If you want to have all attributes on a same row you can. If you dont't have a column for an attribute use ALTER to add it (you have a limit of 2 billions columns per rows). And don't worry about space, cassandra dont allocate space on disk for null values. So a row with 350 null columns and 2 valued columns take as much space as a table with 2 columns valued and 0 null. Answer your question ?